# Localizing a point using distance measurements to four points in 3-D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) article explains how to do trilateration step by step.
I need to extend this process to 3-D. As far as I know, I need four distance measurements in order to calculate a fifth point's coordinates.

Could you help me to extend trilateration to 3-D?

**P.S.** Please do not answer with *"solve the linear system"* I need step by step calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you cited *is* about locating a point in 3-D space. Given three given non-collinear points and the distance from each of these to a point-to-be-found, $P$, the article enables you to narrow down the possible locations of $P$ to at most two distinct points.  If there are two such points, then given a fourth known point not coplanar with the other three, the two candidates for $P$ will be at different distances from that fourth known point, and knowing the distance from that point to $P$, you can determine which candidate is correct.